# Why my Grub 2 version is 1.99?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

Pretty much like the title says.

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04, and my installed grub packages are `grub-pc` and its various dependencies.

The package description says *GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (PC/BIOS version)* but the actual version, also showed at the grub prompt at boot, is 1.99.

Shouldn't the 1.x versions be the old Grub Legacy?

Comment: Based on the grub software repository your theory isn't correct.

Comment: To be honest it's not a theory of mine, I've asked because I had no knowledge about the subject.

Comment: Now you know.  Build 1.99 is considered `Grub 2`

Comment: Not really considering Windows 7 is NT Kernel 6.1 and Windows 8 is actually NT Kernel 6.2.  The proper version was displayed the build number of an application is meaningless to a normal user.

Comment: Well, it wasn't meaningless for me, that's why I've asked it on superuser.com and not on normaluser.com :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, GRUB 1.99 is GRUB 2.